# Making a distance vector of google trends data

Tags: r, google-trends

I have with the help of gtrendsR imported some google trends data and succeeded plotting it. 
Now I'm looking to cluster the data with h.clust but my problem is the data format which I'm not succeeding transforming to distance vector.

The data looks as follows:

```
datestart, date-end, trend1, trend2, trend3 
1   2004-01-04 2004-01-10     57    18     39 
2   2004-01-11 2004-01-17     55    17     39 
3   2004-01-18 2004-01-24     56    20     43 
4   2004-01-25 2004-01-31     55    19     41 
5   2004-02-01 2004-02-07     57    20     39 
6   2004-02-08 2004-02-14     57    18     40
```

To plot the data, I have used a data.frame.

Can anyone help me with ideas of how to transform the data so that I can cluster the "shapes" of the trend into different clusters?

Comment: have you look at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dist.html

Comment: Have you checked the topic "clustering time series" and made some tries? In addition, I don't know what exactly you mean by "clustering the 'shapes'  of the trend into different clusters'  - please elaborate. Full dataset, some images and code might also help.

Comment: I have tried using dist() and dtw() without success. 

By clustering shapes I'm looking for ways of clustering the shapes based on the shape of the curves. 

The code incl dataset grabbed from google: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4686 
Picture of current output
http://postimg.org/image/imjm13k1f/

Answer (score 1):

You can cluster the shapes of your Gmail Trend curves like this:

```
set.seed(1)
library(gtrendsR)
library(dtw)

# Switch https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to on if needed:
gconnect("your_google_email", "your_google_psw")
cotton_trend <- gtrends(c("cotton", "satin", "velvet"), res="week")
d <- dist(t(cotton_trend$trend[, -(1:2)]), method="DTW")
hc <- hclust(d)

# plot the results
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cotton~end, cotton_trend$trend, type="l", ylim=range(cotton_trend$trend[, -(1:2)]), col=3, ylim="")
for (x in 4:ncol(cotton_trend$trend)) lines(x=cotton_trend$trend$end, y=cotton_trend$trend[, x], col=x)
legend("topleft", names(cotton_trend$trend)[-(1:2)], lty=1, col=3:ncol(cotton_trend$trend))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, k=2)

# extract clusters: 
cutree(hc, k=2)
# cotton  satin velvet 
#      1      2      1
```

[image]